# Odd characters showing small table after using tableDiff

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

SQLServer tabeDiff is being used to sync DB's. The Â character has been found in the destination table. I can find nothing on this anywhere, has anyone experienced this? Here is my scenario. Its a .bat file which runs it. Here is an example of a source table.field value:

SM-33®

After tableDiff this appears in the source table.field:

SM-33Â®

How can this be happening? The source is SQLServer 2008R2, destination is SQLServer 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the two databases using the same collation? I would imagine that is what is causing this issue. You should make sure they are using the same collation and then run the tablediff utility again.

More info:

- [Using SQL Server Collations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [SQL Server Collation Fundamentals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

### Risk in changing collation

There is a certain amount of risk in altering the collation of an in-use production database. You need to ensure that it isn't going to mangle the data that is currently there. If all of the current data is ASCII you're probably alright, but it doesn't sound like that is the case if you're having problems like this.

This post: [Collation Hell (Part 2)](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/08/16/Collation-Hell-Part-2.aspx) discusses the risks involved in changing the collation of a database. And this [technet post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/196b4586-1338-434d-ba8c-49fa3c9bdeeb/server-collation-sqllatin1generalcp1cias-versus-latin1generalcias?forum=sqlgetstarted) describes the differences between the two collations you are using.

I wouldn't do this without testing it on a copy of the production database first. I've never actually needed to modify the collation of a database that is in use and I'm not 100% across the differences between all of the collation types, so I can't really give you specific advice. Do some testing to be sure you're not going to further corrupt your data.

Comment: Nice, this could be it.  the 2005 instance is using 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' and the 2008 version is using 'Latin1_General_CI_AS'  could this be it.  What should I be using?

Comment: Align the target database to whatever the source is using.

Comment: OK great, thank you.  Can I bother you with one more quick question.  I have zero experience playing around with collation.  Is this risky, if its changed can it be changed back without issue?  I ask becasue the source DB is internalProduction and the source is production. Thanking you

Comment: I've updated my answer with more information on the risks of changing the collation of your database.

Comment: Your knowledge and advice is exceptional. Thank you for your time, a very good day to you!

Answer (score 1):

The character ® has decimal code value 174 and is therefore not an [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) character which all have code values in range of 0 to 127.

Â® is the character ® stored in the text file encoded with [Unicode](http://www.utf-8.com/) encoding [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), but displayed as [ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_ANSI_code_page) character using code page [Windows 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

So the export of the differences is done fine and the created file (text file?) is okay. You only have to open this UTF-8 encoded file in your text editor / viewer by using UTF-8 if editor / viewer does not automatically detect the UTF-8 encoding.

You can insert at top of the text file `ï»¿` which is hexadecimal EF BB BF which is the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) ([BOM](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)) for UTF-8. That would help text editors / viewers to faster detect that the text file is encoded in UTF-8. But some applications do not interpret those 3 bytes at beginning of a text file as BOM.

Now with knowing that your problem is caused by different encoding of non ASCII characters, you can search for related pages. See for example [Description of storing UTF-8 data in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232580). I suggest to search with the words **Unicode UTF-8 SQL Server**.

Comment: Thank you.  That's excellent information which does explain one side of it very well.  There is no .txt file.  The outcome of this tableDiff firing is to update the destination table.  A .sql file is generated and run.  Inside this .sql file you can see the SQL E.G ProductName=N'SM-33®' BUT the value in the table is SM-33Â® There must be a way of telling tableDiff or SQLServer not to do this?