# Mass replace of problematic character

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

HI there because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522060/odd-characters-showing-small-table-after-using-tablediff) I am face with a task of replacing a character accross multiple tables and fields.   here is a query which deals with it on one table.field location:

```
update productWebSource set ProductName = replace(ProductName, 'Â', '')  where ProductName LIKE '%Â%'
```

As you can see from the query, and as explained in my other post (which is linked above) SQLServer TableDiff is giving me an unwanted 'Â' charater is certain tables.fields. Is there a way I can  write a query that can find and replace all instances of 'Â' in mt entire database and replace these with ''?

This is a SQLServer 2008R2 database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by generating the SQL update statements dynamically. The code below will create an UPDATE statement for each table in the database that has a VARCHAR or NVARCHAR column in it and update those columns to remove the unwanted character. The code below doesn't actually make any changes it simply creates the update statements. You can then copy & paste all of the returned rows and run the SQL.

```sql
WITH tblclmns AS (
    SELECT tbl.name AS tblname, clmn.name AS clmnname
    FROM sys.columns AS clmn
    INNER JOIN sys.types AS t ON clmn.system_type_id=t.system_type_id
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS tbl ON tbl.object_id=clmn.object_id
    WHERE t.name IN ('varchar','nvarchar')
)
SELECT 'UPDATE ' + tblname + ' SET ' +
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + CAST(clmnname AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '=REPLACE(' + clmnname + ',CHAR(194),'''')'
        FROM tblclmns
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS updtClmns
FROM tblclmns
GROUP BY tblname
```

### Disclaimer

The code above is untested and when you run the generated SQL it will cause your entire database to be modified. This could put a heavy load on the SQL server (don't do it in production during business hours) and you MUST double check the generated to code to ensure you are not updating any tables or columns you shouldn't and that it won't do anything you don't want it to. Use at your own risk...

Comment: Slick, very slick.  Your time and effort is very much appreciated!  A fine day to you...