# TableDiff producing NULL as strings from dateTime fields all of a sudden

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, batch-processing

This may very well be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522060/odd-characters-showing-small-table-after-using-tablediff) which in summary is almost certainly a DB collation difference between the source DB (SQL 2008r2) and destination DB (SQL 2005) that is causing the issue, as pointed out by the super helpful @Mike D.

Although it could be related I thought this issue deserved its own post. The issue, when this table diff is run its producing an insert statement which gives 'Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string' because the insert statement for some reason looks like this:

```
VALUES (N'Null',0,N'A',N'Null',N'Null',0,N'Null',Null,
```

The N'Null' values are the issue.  This did not used to happen when going from SQL 2005 to SQL 2005. Its only started happening when this changed from SQL 2008r2 to SQL 2005.  Is there any way I can make tableDiff stop doing this N'Null' and start doing this Null?  If I remove the single quotes the query runs...

Note - The dataType of these problematic fields in the source is dateTime, the dataType in the destination is also dateTime.  Becasue of this, my understanding is that this should not happen?

Comment: I have now 100% ruled out any related collation issue.  TableDiff produces the same issue when running against 2 identical 2008R2 SQL Server DB's.  How do I fix this.  TableDiff is translating a genuine NULL from  dateTime field into N'Null' in the INSERT statement, hoe can I prevent this?

Comment: The solution was to Apply SQLServer 2008R2 SP 2.  This was a known bug  that only occured in 2008R2 with not only dateTime dataTypes but also others.  I am unsure abou the forum policy about accepting own solutions?? More info about known bug here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/684614/tablediff-generates-incorrect-sql-for-datetime-with-null-value-sql-server-2008-r2

Comment: On SO you are encouraged to post and accept your own answers - see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score -1):

There is a huge difference between N'Null' and Null. N'Null' is considered as a string, whereas **NULL** means nothing or not defined. So if you insert N'Null' in datetime field then it will throw exception as it will try to convert this string into a datetime, and doing so will fail all the time, whereas in case of **NULL** it will just not save anything in that column. If you have to keep the column blank i.e. you don't want to pass any value now then you have insert **NULL**.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I failed to explain this issue properly.  I am aware of the difference.  TableDiff is creating the query by comparing two identical tables.  The source table.field value is a genuine NULL but it producing a query which contains N'Null' this is my issue.  can this be the collation difference explained in the link in my initial post?  Any ideas would be great